# DoH setup using dnscrypt-proxy

Tags: dns, doh

So for a while now I've been using dnscrypt-proxy to setup DoH using cloudflare's **1.1.1.1**. But recently, I've been noticing that instead of using Cloudflare's DNS it reverts back to my ISP's DNS server.

Going to https://1.1.1.1/help/ says that I am on DNS over HTTPS but instead of cloudflare's DNS I am on my ISP's DNS.

I can confirm that dnscrypt-proxy is running, its service is installed and running, and I have set the connection settings on Control Panel to 127.0.0.1, and whenever I ran dnscrypt-proxy on powershell to resolve a website it shows the resolver IP to be Cloudflare's, and not my ISP's. It once ran correctly but it suddenly reverted back to my ISP's DNS, and I am very sure I did nothing to the config file. Is this a settings mistake or is it something else?

*Forgive me if this post is unclear/not detailed enough or not on the right place, I am new to stackexchange and English is not my first language.*

Answer (score 0):

So I don't know if anyone else experiences this problem, but I figured out that this is due to Windows somehow prioritizing the alternate DNS server (which I have set as 8.8.8.8, although it seems that at the end it still uses my ISP's DNS anyway) instead of the primary DNS server which I have configured for dnscrypt-proxy.

It's really silly to be honest. All I need to do is to leave the alternate DNS server blank and now it works. Although I still don't quite understand as to why Windows chooses to use the alternate DNS server **everytime** instead of the primary one.